# What is the best way to filter through JSON with no key in Python

Tags: python, json

I am using an API that locates the general area of an IP address and spits out the data in JSON format. I am not sure how to go about parsing the information as the JSON is lacking a key.

Here is the unparsed JSON:

```
{
  "ip": "64.44.55.212",
  "country_code2": "US",
  "country_code3": "USA",
  "country_name": "United States",
  "state_prov": "Illinois",
  "district": "",
  "city": "West Chicago",
  "zipcode": "60185",
  "latitude": "41.87590",
  "longitude": "-88.24900"
}
```

The desired result is this:

```
64.44.55.212
US
USA
United States
Illinois

West Chicago
60185
41.87590
-88.24900
```

This is what JSON looks like with a key:

```
{
  "people": [
    {
       "name": "Rick"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what JSON looks like without a key:

```
{
  {
    "name": "Rick"
  }
}
```

Comment: please, share sample data and desired output that is expected...

Comment: Thank you, I have added the mentioned fields.

Comment: `dict.values()`

Comment: What do you exactly mean when you say 'JSON is lacking a title object'? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Do you just want to print the contents? Your question is unclear. To refer to that piece of data as _unparsed JSON_ is... bizarre. The use of the words _filter_ and _title object_ is inaccurate at best, and ambiguous. I’m seriously confused.

Comment: I apologize for my lack of JSON vocabulary as I just learned how to use it yesterday. I believe the correct term would be key. As for the "unparsed JSON", I just meant that that was the JSON I was receiving directly from the API, in comparison to the desired result which had removed everything but the actual values held in the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you get access to the object in say `data`

```
data = {
    "ip": "64.44.55.212",
    "country_code2": "US",
    "country_code3": "USA",
    "country_name": "United States",
    "state_prov": "Illinois",
    "district": "",
    "city": "West Chicago",
    "zipcode": "60185",
    "latitude": "41.87590",
    "longitude": "-88.24900"
}

print("\n".join(data.values()))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for _, value in dict_.items():
   print(value)

#op
64.44.55.212
US
USA
United States
Illinois

West Chicago
60185
41.87590
-88.24900
```